# Regular expression which match the entire line if its text start with

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I need some help to write a regular expression which can match the entire line if its text start with:

`// tslint:`

for example regex will match:

`// tslint:disable-next-line:no-expression-statement`

I have tried `^.*//tslint:.*$` but with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try escaping the backslashes `^.*\/\/\stslint:.*$`

Comment: Try `\/\/.*tslint:.*`

Comment: I tried but they do not work

Comment: Can you update the question with how you are using the code?

Comment: I just tried it in vscode find / replace and it seems to work.

Comment: `^.*\/\/\s*tslint:.*$` should work

Comment: What about `^\s*\/\/ tslint:.+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces

```
.*\/\/.*tslint:.*
```

will work better

Comment: sorry it does not work, I am using in vscode find/replace

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the two forward slashes. Try the following expression:

```
^\/\/\stslint\:.*$
```

To explain:

1. `^` matches the start of the string;
2. `\/\/` matches the two forward-slashes (the backward-slashes escape the special character);
3. `\s` matches exactly one whitespace;
4. `tslint\:` matches "tslint:";
5. `.*` matches 0 or more characters of any kind;
6. `$` matches the end of the string.